# Confused about determining super mesh or not

Tags: circuit-analysis

This is an easy question related to **Mesh analysis**. It is a beginners question. In the figure that I have attached there is a **5A** current source between two loops and there is common register of **5 ohm** as well. In this case should there exist super-mesh or converting the current source into voltage source by 5*5 i.e 10 V works or there is no need to use super-mesh. Sorry if there is the repeated question. I am really confused.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a super-mesh because you don't know the voltage across the current source.

Note that the current source links the two mesh currents. It forces the condition i1 - i2 = 5A.

The equation for the super-mesh is: -10V + 5 * i1 + 10 * i2 = 0

Since i2 is linked to i1 through the current source, we have: i2 = i1 - 5A

The rest is left as an exercise.

The 5ohm resistor in series with the current source does not matter, because the current source will force 5A now matter how big or small the series resistor is.